# Show exposé/"All Application Windows" from the dock

Tags: dock, expose

Is there anyway to show all the windows for one application (aka Exposé) from the window icon on the launcher? I know it is possible by right-clicking on the icon and then "Show All Windows", but I wanted a more direct way, for example:

- Long pressing on the app icon to show exposé;
  or
- Double-clicking the icon;
  or
- Shift/Command/... + click;
  or
- If the application is already on focus, clicking its icon on the dock will show exposé.

Is this possible?

Comment: `Long pressing on the app icon to show exposé` was actually the default behavior in Snow Leopard, but then in Lion they reverted it back to just displaying the context menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to (sort of) do it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76103/38367

The following command will enable the mouse scroll-up on an app icon to open exposé:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock scroll-to-open -bool true
killall Dock
```

More info on: http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/30/enable-hidden-stack-gestures-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the following steps:

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Go to Trackpad
3. Go to More Gestures
4. Check App Exposé
5. Done!

Comment: This only works with the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

cmd-Tab to the app without releasing cmd key. Then press 1.